# mouse hover image background color was not changing for particular images

Tags: html, css

Hi in the below code some of the images when mouse hover it's not displaying background.but some images are showing background color because of the image or any other reason.

as well as how to change image when mouse hover or it is possible to change the color of the image to white any way it's possible please help me

can any one help me

```css
.specilites{
    width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding-top:7px;
    color:#008080;
    font-size:30px;
}

.specilites img{

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius:50px;
    -moz-border-radius:50px;
    border-radius:50px;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    display:inline-block;
 
     border: 1.5px solid #008080;
}
.specilites h1{
        width: 1050px;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        padding-top:7px;
        color:#000000;
        font-size:20px;
    }
.specilites  tr {
        font-size:15px;
  padding-top:7px;
  font-weight: bold;
     /*    display:block;*/

    }
 
.specilites img:hover {
    background-color: #40E0D0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="specilites">
 <h1>Specialties</h1>
       <table>
      <tr>
           <td><a href="#"><img src="img/Ambulance-128 (3).png"/></a></td>
     <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">Accident & Emergency Care</a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="img/Bone-128 (1).png"/></a></td>
   <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">Bone & Joints</a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="img/brain1.png"/></a></td>
   <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">Brains & Nerves</a></td>
   <td><a href="#"><img src="img/Astro-Cancer-128 (2).png"/></a></td>
      <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">Cancer Care</a></td>
        </tr>
          <td><a href="#"><img src="img/Children-128.png"/></a></td>
    <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">Child Care</a></td>
          <td><a href="#"><img src="img/clinical.png"/></a></td>
    <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">Clinical Research</a></td>
     <td><a href="#"><img src="img/Dental-128.png"/></a></td>
     <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">Dental Care</a></td>
     <td><a href="#"><img src="img/ear,nose.png"/></a></td>
     <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">Ear,nose & Throat</a></td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><a href="#"><img src="img/kidneys-128.png" /></a></td>
     <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">Dialysis & Kidney Transplants</a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><img src="img/eye.png" /></a></td>
      <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">Eye Care</a></td>
     <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#"><img src="img/general_surgery.png" /></a></td>
    <td><a style="color:#008080"href="#">General Surgery</a></td>
     <td><a href="#"><img src="img/genetics.png" /></a></td>
     <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">Genetics</a></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
          <td><a href="#"><img src="img/Medicine-128 (1).png" /></a></td>
     <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">General Medicine</a></td>
           <td><a href="#"><img src="img/Football-02-128.png" /></a></td>
     <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">Sports Medicine</a></td>
     <td><img src="img/Heart-ECG-128.png" /></a></td>
     <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">ICU & Critical Care</a></td>
     <td><a href="#"><img src="img/home_care.png"  /></a></td>
     <td><a style="color:#008080" href="#">Home Care</a></td>
  </tr>
         
      </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of background-color use background.

**UPDATE**
you can do this

```
.specilites img:hover {

    background-image: url('yourimage.png');

}
```

Comment: @hspcare Wait.. you want to change image on hover? You can do it simply with css but all images will be changed to one picture if you hover over them.. Check update

Comment: but i want to happens both background color should be change as well as image should change

Comment: you can do it both just add there background: #color;

Comment: no use not working it showing only background color was not showing

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a jquery code?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.specialties').mouseenter(function() {
            $('.specialties').fadeTo('fast', 0.2);
            });
        $('.specialties').mouseleave(function() {
            $('.specialties').fadeTo('fast', 1);
            });
```

Comment: did you make sure to make it its own file with the .js extension then call it from your html file with: <script type='text/javascript' src='name of your .js source'></script>?

Comment: same file i wrote the javascript